# Is there a easy way to let iphone install a app which use adhoc provision profile from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

My requirement is this, because we can use Xcode run to install my app to my iPhone conveniently.

But, as you know, use this method to install app, this is debug app, it did not use `distribution provision profile` or `Adhoc provision profile`, it is use `development provision profile`.

If I want access my goal, I must archive the `.ipa`, and export as `Adhoc`, so I can in itunes to install the `.ipa` file, then it is using `Adhoc provision profile`.

1. But this may take me a long time to aceess that.
2. It is very not easy to debug.

So, is there a simple and convenient way to get my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the iPhone to your system and set the Adhoc profile select your device and install the app in this way app will install in your device than app will close and a popup is open in Xcode just ignore that and open the app in your Device

Comment: do you mean in the Target -> Building Setting -> Signing -> Provisioning profile to choose ?

Comment: in iOS 10, the Provisioning Profile is `Automatic`, and before's provisioning profile is deprecated.

Comment: @aircraft a small correction: provisioning profile is automatic from Xcode 8 and later.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488782/xcode-8-provisioning-profile-vs-provisioning-profile-deprecated/39506131#39506131

Comment: @Nhat Dinh, I mean how to choose `Adhoc provisioning profile` in Xcode8, bro.