# Code signing with provision profile in XCode 8 shows depricated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Code signing with provision profile in XCode 8 shows depricated!!

Can't able to export build with distribution Adhoc profile.

[image]

Comment: Look at solution in this question: [stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488782/xcode-8-provisioning-profile-vs-provisioning-profile-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

The signing system has been rewritten to include a new mode for automatically managing signing assets, in addition to a dedicated manual mode where the profiles for the target must be explicitly selected. When automatically managing signing assets, Xcode will create signing certificates, update app IDs, and create provisioning profiles. For manual mode, only custom created profiles can be selected and Xcode will not modify or create any signing assets. Xcode now encodes profiles in the target using the PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER build setting. This setting allows specifying both the team ID and the name or identifier of the profile.

There are some Signing relate known Issues with Xcode 8.1 you should known look at this link: [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_39)