# How to change provisioning profile

Tags: ios, qt, qt-creator, provisioning-profile, qt5.9

At this moment, I've successfully managed to run the calculator example that comes with Qt Creator under iOS apps section through the Simulator and the actual iPhone (i.e. in my case iPhone 5s). Qt insists that the provisioning profile must be provided. I've provided an ad-hoc provisioning profile with the following setting

[image]

When I run the project it shows me this message

```
No profiles for 'com.test.profile.calculator' were 
found:-1: error: Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 
'com.test.profile.calculator'.
```

It insists on using this profile  `com.test.profile.calculator` whereas in the setting I've provided my own. I went to the folder where the Xcode project has been generated and I did run it. It works and the app has been deployed successfully to my iPhone 5s. **My question** is how can I change the provisioning profile name? There is nothing in `.pro` regarding this issue.

```
QT += widgets
HEADERS       = button.h \
                calculator.h
SOURCES       = button.cpp \
                calculator.cpp \
                main.cpp

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/widgets/widgets/calculator
INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488782/xcode-8-provisioning-profile-vs-provisioning-profile-deprecated

Comment: @JagathishS, I need Qt to pass  my provisioning profile to Xcode 8.

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Automatically manage signing` and it will do some fix itself. Do you try it?

[image]

Comment: This will change the provisioning profile to default which in this case `'com.test.profile.calculator'`

Comment: I've already provided my own but Qt insists on using `com.test.profile.calculator`

Comment: You can try to use `fastlane`. And set `Provision profile` what you want. It will automatically repair and set what you need. https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh

Comment: I need to know where Qt keeps modifying profiles' names.